# Передача в модель структуры данных, и возврат обьекта , выстроенной по структуре

Tags: java, android, классы, retrofit, data-structures

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы реализовать в мобильном приложении унифицированную модель, в которую поступает URL и структура ответа от сервера, в ответ приходит готовый объект с которым можно работать.

Скажите как такое реализовать, есть ли пример похожего решения?

Comment: Пишите свой конвертер для ретрофита если ни один из готовых вам не подходит.

Comment: Чет не  до конца понятно, что именно вам нужно!